# Validate File Extension IN Drupal 8 Entity Form

Tags: forms, entity, drupal-8

I have an Entity in Drupal 8 named `visual_tracker_entity` Here is my entity,

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\visual_tracker\Entity\VisaulTrackerEntity.
 */

namespace Drupal\visual_tracker\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\visual_tracker\VisaulTrackerEntityInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;

/**
 * Defines the Visaul tracker entity entity.
 *
 * @ingroup visual_tracker
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "visaul_tracker_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("Visaul tracker entity"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\visual_tracker\VisaulTrackerEntityListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\visual_tracker\Entity\VisaulTrackerEntityViewsData",
 *
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\visual_tracker\Form\VisaulTrackerEntityForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\visual_tracker\Form\VisaulTrackerEntityForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\visual_tracker\Form\VisaulTrackerEntityForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\visual_tracker\Form\VisaulTrackerEntityDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "access" = "Drupal\visual_tracker\VisaulTrackerEntityAccessControlHandler",
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\visual_tracker\VisaulTrackerEntityHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   base_table = "visaul_tracker_entity",
 *   admin_permission = "administer visaul tracker entity entities",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "address" = "address",
 *     "lat"="lat",
 *     "lng" = "lng"
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/structure/visaul_tracker_entity/{visaul_tracker_entity}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/structure/visaul_tracker_entity/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/structure/visaul_tracker_entity/{visaul_tracker_entity}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/structure/visaul_tracker_entity/{visaul_tracker_entity}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/structure/visaul_tracker_entity",
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "visaul_tracker_entity.settings"
 * )
 */
class VisaulTrackerEntity extends ContentEntityBase implements VisaulTrackerEntityInterface {
  use EntityChangedTrait;
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function preCreate(EntityStorageInterface $storage_controller, array &$values) {
    parent::preCreate($storage_controller, $values);
    $values += array(
      'user_id' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getName() {
    return $this->get('name')->value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setName($name) {
    $this->set('name', $name);
    return $this;
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getAddress() {
    return $this->get('address')->value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setAddress($address) {
    $this->set('address', $address);
    return $this;
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getLatittude() {
    return $this->get('lat')->value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setLatitude($lat) {
    $this->set('lat', $lat);
    return $this;
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getLongitude() {
    return $this->get('lng')->value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setLongitude($lng) {
    $this->set('lng', $lng);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCreatedTime() {
    return $this->get('created')->value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setCreatedTime($timestamp) {
    $this->set('created', $timestamp);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getOwner() {
    return $this->get('user_id')->entity;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getOwnerId() {
    return $this->get('user_id')->target_id;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setOwnerId($uid) {
    $this->set('user_id', $uid);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setOwner(UserInterface $account) {
    $this->set('user_id', $account->id());
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isPublished() {
    return (bool) $this->getEntityKey('status');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setPublished($published) {
    $this->set('status', $published ? NODE_PUBLISHED : NODE_NOT_PUBLISHED);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('ID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The ID of the Visaul tracker entity entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
    $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
      ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The UUID of the Visaul tracker entity entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    $fields['user_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Authored by'))
      ->setDescription(t('The user ID of author of the Visaul tracker entity entity.'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'user')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setDefaultValueCallback('Drupal\node\Entity\Node::getCurrentUserId')
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'author',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'weight' => 5,
        'settings' => array(
          'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
          'size' => '60',
          'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
          'placeholder' => '',
        ),
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['my_new_file'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
      ->setLabel(t('My New File'))
      ->setDescription(t('The name of the Visaul tracker entity entity.'))
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'file',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
    $fields['address'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Address'))
      ->setDescription(t('The addres of the Visaul tracker entity entity.'))
      ->setSettings(array(
        'max_length' => 250,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
    $fields['lat'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Latitiude'))
      ->setDescription(t('The latiitude of the Visaul tracker entity entity.'))
      ->setSettings(array(
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
    $fields['lng'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Longitude'))
      ->setDescription(t('The name of the Visaul tracker entity entity.'))
      ->setSettings(array(
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['status'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
      ->setLabel(t('Publishing status'))
      ->setDescription(t('A boolean indicating whether the Visaul tracker entity is published.'))
      ->setDefaultValue(TRUE);

    $fields['langcode'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('language')
      ->setLabel(t('Language code'))
      ->setDescription(t('The language code for the Visaul tracker entity entity.'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'language_select',
        'weight' => 10,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
      ->setLabel(t('Created'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was created.'));

    $fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
      ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was last edited.'));

    return $fields;
  }

}
```

I need add validation rule for file type field. The default file type is come with `.txt` extension. I want to only allow `.xls` and `.xlsx` . 
This is the `file` filed,

```
  $fields['my_new_file'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
          ->setLabel(t('My New File'))
          ->setDescription(t('The name of the Visaul tracker entity entity.'))
          ->setDefaultValue('')
          ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
            'label' => 'above',
            'type' => 'file',
            'weight' => -4,
          ))
          ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
            'type' => 'file',
            'weight' => -4,
          ))
          ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
          ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Note dupe question on Drupal.StackExchange has some additional info. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193402/validate-file-extension-in-drupal-8-entity-form/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after digging drupal 8 core APIs.
If we're using a file field, then we can set the "file_extensions" setting. You can find out more information about a "file" type by going to the [FileItem](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!src!Plugin!Field!FieldType!FileItem.php/class/FileItem/8) API.

```
$fields['my_new_file'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
   ->setSetting('file_extensions', 'xls xlsx');
```